# Controller don't work on LARAVEL 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I started using Laravel today, but I have some problems. Controllers don't run.

This is my controller:

```
<?php 
class HomeController extends Controller {
/*

 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
/**
 * Show the application welcome screen to the user.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('welcome');
}
public function contact(){
    return view(pages.contact);
}
?>
```

and this is my route:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
return "hello";
});

Route::get('contact','HomeController@contact');  
?>
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the namespace to the beginning of the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

You can also run this command when creating a controller

`php artisan make:controller HomeController`

In, addition as the other answer mentioned, the view name needs to be inside quotes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should be like this

```
public function contact(){
    return view('pages.contact'); // View name must be inside ' '
}
```

also you dont need the closing tag for php `?>`

Comment: what is the error can you tell me? also do you have a View called `contact.blade.php` inside of a  folder called `pages` ?